# Ladder Script Glitch Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the basics of my ladder script covered already, the only problem that I am having is when a player wants to go down the ladder. I get this glitchy movement as shown in the video below. Would appreciate any help! https://youtu.be/o9r-uELWQEg

```
void Update()
            {
                // Smoothing calls
                SmoothInput();
                SmoothSpeed();

                // Calculate calls
                CalculateSpeed();
                CalculateFinalDirection();
                CalculateFinalMovement();

                // Apply Calls
                if (!m_movementInputData.IsClimbing)
                {
                    ApplyGravity();
                    ApplyMovement();
                }

                // Misc
                RotateTowardsCamera();
                FootStepSystem();
                LadderSystem();
            }

            void LadderSystem()
            {
                if (m_movementInputData.IsClimbing)
                {
                    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
                    {
                        Vector3 _yDir = transform.up * m_climbSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
                        Vector3 _zDir = transform.forward * m_climbSpeed;

                        m_characterController.Move((_yDir + _zDir) * Time.deltaTime);
                    }
                }
            }

            void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
            {
                if (col.tag == "Ladder")
                {
                    m_movementInputData.IsClimbing = true;
                }
            }

            void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
            {
                if (col.tag == "Ladder")
                {
                    m_movementInputData.IsClimbing = false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: After further review, it was understood that the `_zDir` part of the ladder movement was creating the problem as when attempting to climb down the ladder, it would push the player off it due to the forward movement.

Removing the `_zDir` part wasn't a solution however as a forward movement was needed to get off the ladder when climbing up, and a backward movement was required to avoid getting stuck when getting on the ladder to climb down.

As such, `* Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` was added to `_zDir` in order to get a forward movement when going up and a backward movement when going down.

```
Vector3 _zDir = transform.forward * m_climbSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

However, in that setup, the player would be eventually pushed off too far from the ladder and fall when going down, because of the backward movement.

To counteract that, two trigger boxes with a "Ladder Extremity" tag where added  on top of the original ladder trigger box, one at the top and one at the bottom. In the ladder movement, `_zDir` is only computed when the player stand in one of these extremity. As such, forward/backward movement is only applied when actually needed, namely when entering and when leaving the ladder. This gives us the following code:

```
    void LadderSystem()
    {
        if (m_movementInputData.IsClimbing)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                Vector3 _verticalDir = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) ? Transform.up : Transform.down;
                Vector3 _yDir = _verticalDir * m_climbSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
                Vector3 _zDir = Vector3.zero;
                if (m_movementInputData.IsClimbingExtremity)
                {
                    _zDir = transform.forward * m_climbSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
                }

                m_characterController.Move((_yDir + _zDir) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "Ladder")
        {
            m_movementInputData.IsClimbing = true;
        }
        if (col.tag == "Ladder Extremity")
        {
            m_movementInputData.IsClimbingExtremity = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "Ladder")
        {
            m_movementInputData.IsClimbing = false;
        }
        if (col.tag == "Ladder Extremity")
        {
            m_movementInputData.IsClimbingExtremity = false;
        }
    }
```

Below is my original answer which was incorrect as I missed the `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` which was handling the direction being up or down.

---

Well, you simply didn't code the behavior to go down...

I suppose you wanted to have a ladder where pressing W/Forward would make you go up while pressing S/Backward would make you go down. But with the condition `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))`, both input will lead to the exact same behavior, namely going up. This is why you're getting the glitchy movement: you're pressing S which is making you take the ladder but the ladder makes you go up which takes you off the ladder.

Most likely, you simply need to swap the `transform.up` for a `transform.down`  when you're pressing S instead of W in that line:

```
Vector3 _yDir = transform.up * m_climbSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

This would give you something like this:

```
        void LadderSystem()
        {
            if (m_movementInputData.IsClimbing)
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
                {
                    Vector3 _verticalDir = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) ? Transform.up : Transform.down;
                    Vector3 _yDir = _verticalDir * m_climbSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
                    Vector3 _zDir = transform.forward * m_climbSpeed;

                    m_characterController.Move((_yDir + _zDir) * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: GetAxis("Vertical") returns a positive 1 for W, and a -1 for S by default. So this is not true.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Input.GetAxis("Vertical") returns 1 or -1 for forward or backwards. Also, as far as I'm aware of Transform.down does not exist...

Comment: My bad indeed, I missed the GetAxis("Vertical"). Does the issue also occurs if you start the game on the platform and attempt going down the ladder (meaning you don't have to go up the ladder first) ?

Comment: @Vale No problem. When starting from the ground and moving up it does not occur.

Comment: I meant starting from up top and going down. Instead of starting from the ground, going up, then going down.

Comment: @Vale Not quite sure what you mean... did you check the video link I provided?

Comment: I did. I am asking what happens if you start the game with the player already on top of the building and then try going down the ladder (instead of having to climb the ladder up first). Basically I wondering if going down the ladder is always not working or if it might be happening because you climbed it up first.

Comment: @Vale Gotcha. Just tested it and still have the same issue.

Comment: I might have an idea. Can you try to remove the `Vector3 _zDir = transform.forward * m_climbSpeed;` line and see what happens ? I think it might be making you go off the ladder when you try to go down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205317/discussion-between-omar-dajani-and-vale).